# Manual set created_at property [Rails 3]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Trying to set the created_at date manually:

```
entry = Entry.new
entry.text = tweet['text']
entry.source = 'tweet'
entry.user_id = user.id
entry.latitude = coords[1]
entry.longitude = coords[0]
entry.created_at = Chromium(tweet.created_at)
```

Getting the following error:

```
 undefined method `created_at' for #<Hash:0x1036af910>
```

How can I avoid this? I would like to keep created_at's default functionality as not all entries are entered in this way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem isn't with the created_at method of the ActiveRecord object. 
I think what's spitting the error here is actually the `created_at` method being called on your `tweet` object.

See above - you use

```
entry.text = tweet['text']
```

(`tweet` is a hash)... but then

```
entry.created_at = Chromium(tweet.created_at)
```

complains that the Hash doesn't have a method called `created_at`

```
 undefined method `created_at' for #<Hash:0x1036af910>
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem here is that there isn't a `created_at` method on the `tweet` object, which is a Hash. You probably meant

```
entry.created_at = Chromium(tweet['created_at'])
```

However, when an object is saved for the first time, Rails will override the `created_at` attribute. This is a pretty fixed behaviour and you won't be able to override it without messing something else up.

Better to create a new datetime column, for example `tweeted_at` and use that.

Comment: Thanks! You were both right, but I saw mylescarricks first. Thank you :)

Comment: Just noticed your comment about not being able to override it. I have various different types of entry going in, some pulled in from external sources via cron/rake and some entered through the rails UI which could do with the date being added. Should I just call the field something else so it avoids the automagic, or have a imported_at which is used if not from web?

Comment: Yes, better to avoid the name `created_at`. Even if you can get Rails stop doing what it wants to do, plenty of other plugins might expect a `created_at` field to be doing what it usually does. Better to be safe than annoyed